# Рабочий стол по умолчанию

Tags: macos, настройка

Работаю с несколькими рабочими столами в 10.14.4 версии, за каждым столом закреплены свои приложения, но после перезагрузки загружается рандомный рабочий стол. 
Каким образом я могу выбрать рабочий стол (например №3) при перезапуске, или включении-выключении?

Answer (score 0):

Возможен такой подход:

Создаём скрипт Applescript для перехода на конкретный рабочий стол (для примера здесь рассматриваем рабочий стол 3):

```
do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control"
delay 0.5
try
  tell application "System Events" to click (first button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "exit to Desktop 3") of list 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
on error
  tell application "System Events" to click (first button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "exit to Desktop 3") of list 2 of group 1 of process "Dock"
end try
```

Теперь заставляем скрипт запускаться при логине:

->System Preferences->Users & Groups->[Login Items] -> выбираем + и затем созданный скрипт.

Comment: Круто! Я, на самом деле, думал это проще можно сделать.